# how to copy artifacts from one pipe to another azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]I have two pipelines in Azure DevOps, what I want to achieve is as below:

1. Pipeline 1 build successfully and generate artifacts.
2. Pipeline 2 need to work on result of Pipeline 1.

So I am looking for a way to take artifacts of pipeline 1 as an input of pipeline 2.

Comment: What's the concrete problem? Doesn't work the task of the screenshot?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Can you share your solution if you have found a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

To share artifacts from one pipeline to another in Azure DevOps, you can use Azure Artifacts.

To do so, you would have to do the following:

- Create a new Azure Artifacts Feed
- Publish an artifact from the first pipeline
- Download that artifact again in the second pipeline

This link provides a great starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: tried this thing but getting error like 

 ##[error]Failed in getBuildApi with error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate ##[error]Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: Since you are getting the same error in different scenario's, something else might be wrong. Are you using the hosted agent pool or some private pool?

Answer (score 0):

In Pipeline 2 just add a [Download build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task:

[image]

Configure the task to download Pipeline 1 artifacts.

Comment: I tried this thing but giving error like
##[error]Failed in getBuildApi with error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
##[error]Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: Can you share the task configuration?

Comment: I added screen shot for that, Build Files is name of my artifacts in Pipeline 1